# Magnitude and Direction of Magnetic Field Homework Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematical-physics, magnetic-fields

> A $150~\text{V}$ battery is connected across two parallel metal plates of area $28.5~\text{cm}^2$ and separation $0.00820~\text{m}$. A beam of alpha particles (charge $+2e$, mass $6.64 \times 10^{-27}~\text{kg}$) is accelerated from rest through a potential difference of $1.75~\text{kV}$ and enters the region between the plates perpendicular to the electric field.
>
> What magnitude and direction of magnetic field are needed so that the alpha particles emerge undeflected from between the plates?

Comment: Welcome to Phys.SE, Phys.SE isn't homework help site. Phys.SE Help Center says that: "Do my homework"-type physics questions shouldn't be asked here: "example: "A 4kg ball is traveling at 8m/s in the x direction, how do I find..", For more info please visit: [Help Center](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

The answer, to be quick, is velocity  $$v = E/B$$. Work out the others from there.

The hint is to consider magnetic forces (Lorentz) vs the electric forces (Coloumb) and ask yourself how they oppose during equilibrium.